# How to create an error message if user inputs string into int array?

Tags: c#, arrays

basically i want the program to display an error message when they enter a string into an int array, but i dont know how to do it also how can terminate and input when the user presses the " * " character:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // array
        int[] ft = new int[2];

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("number:");
            ft[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); 
        }
        Console.Read();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace this line `ft[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());` with

```
string input = Console.ReadLine();
if (input == "*") // first check, if user wants to exit the app
    break; // or return;

int number;
if (!int.TryParse(input, out number)) // validate input
{
    Console.WriteLine("not a number");
    // here you could do i-- and continue;
}
else
{
    ft[i] = number;
}
```

Comment: @Ashraf96 I don't understand what you want to do. If you have a different question, you should create a new question.

Answer (score 2):

use `TryParse` to check if it's an int:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("number:");    
    string input = Console.ReadLine();

    int num;
    if(int.TryParse(input, out num))
        ft[i] = num;
    else 
        break;
}
```

if it *is* an int, TryParse will return true, and `num` will be the int value.  If not, `TryParse` will return false.

This is a very common way to validate input.

Answer (score 1):

Use [int.TryParse()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) instead, because it allows you to check for parsing errors without relying on throwing and catching of exceptions.

```
int tmp;

bool success = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out tmp); 
if (success)
{ 
    ft[i] = tmp;
}
else // error handling here
```